# Getting VNC server to work over ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome

Tags: 16.04, gnome, vnc

So like the subject I am trying to get vnc to work with Gnome.
I have installed gnome and vncserver using the following command.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo apt-get install vnc4server
```

my xstartup file is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
 unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup.  
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey. 
#vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
gnome-session &

#metacity &
#gnome-settings-daemon &
#gnome-panel &
#nautilus &
```

I get a grey window.. I being trying based on the suggestions of google and yet no luck.. Though vnc server works or should I say the display shows up when I use XFCE.. but I am trying to use gnome(not classic)..

Please help..

UPDATE:could not figure out how to get vnc4server/vino to work.. But x11vnc worked just fine..

Comment: can you consider trying x2go? I find it faster and more reliable on ubuntu these days.

Comment: yup.. tried that but I was had some problem even with that. I had issues with it starting on Mac.. so just gave up on immediately..

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu comes with default remote sharing, to enable that just execute `vino-preferences` in terminal and enable remote sharing with password.

Comment: I did try this first.. But when I try to connect from the Mac with realvnc, it say connection refused..
Also I do get a GTK message: GTKdialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.